# Combine 2 columns into 1 column by a group

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with two fields: `Category` and `Name`.

I call and an endpoint and I get something like this.

```
+----------+----------+
| Category | Name     |
+----------+----------+
| A        | product1 |
+----------+----------+
| A        | product2 |
+----------+----------+
| A        | product3 |
+----------+----------+
| B        | product4 |
+----------+----------+
| B        | product5 |
+----------+----------+
| C        | product6 |
+----------+----------+
| D        | product7 |
+----------+----------+
| D        | product8 |
+----------+----------+
```

But I need to transform this array into a single column so that a category comes first then the names under the same category come second.

Here is the result that I'm looking for.

```
+------------+
| One Column |
+------------+
| A          |
+------------+
| product1   |
+------------+
| product2   |
+------------+
| product3   |
+------------+
| B          |
+------------+
| product4   |
+------------+
| product5   |
+------------+
| C          |
+------------+
| product6   |
+------------+
| D          |
+------------+
| product7   |
+------------+
| product8   |
+------------+
```

Comment: Can you please add your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the items with a helper variable that stores the last value.

```js
let data = [
  { "Category": "A", "Name": "product1" },
  { "Category": "A", "Name": "product2" },
  { "Category": "A", "Name": "product3" },
  { "Category": "B", "Name": "product4" },
  { "Category": "B", "Name": "product5" },
  { "Category": "C", "Name": "product6" },
  { "Category": "D", "Name": "product7" },
  { "Category": "D", "Name": "product8" }
];

console.log(transform(data, 'Category', 'Name'));

function transform(data, categoryField, nameField) {
  let last = null; // Helper
  return data.reduce((result, item) => {
    if (last == null || last[categoryField] != item[categoryField]) {
      result.push(item[categoryField]);
    }
    result.push(item[nameField]);
    last = item; // Update
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```